# how to change background-color with js in Select2 4.0.6-rc.1 full

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-select2

I want to change an specific select by id -> background-color

I tried

//css

```
.required-input {background-color :rgb(250, 255, 189)}


$(id).select2({
        data: data,
        width: '100%',
        placeholder: "Select an option",
        allowClear: true,
        containerCssClass : "required-input"
    })
```

Comment: Hello Percy, welcome to Stack Overflow! Maybe you could include more details on your question, so we can understand better and be more helpful. The code you wrote here are not changing any background directly... It would be helpful if you can include the `required-input` css style too...

Comment: @JGFMK thank you.
Cristian Porto thank you for your recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `background-color` property as inside API configuration: in the [Docs](https://select2.org/configuration/options-api) you can see the `containerCss`, you can use it for importing your own `CSS` as inline `CSS`. Also you can use `camleCase` to add multi-parts `CSS` properties.

```
$(id).select2({
    data: data,
    width: '100%',
    placeholder: "Select an option",
    allowClear: true,
    containerCssClass : "required-input",
    containerCss: { 'background-color': 'rgb(250, 255, 189) !important' }
})
```

Or:

```
$(id).select2({
    data: data,
    width: '100%',
    placeholder: "Select an option",
    allowClear: true,
    containerCssClass : "required-input",
    containerCss: { backgroundColor: 'rgb(250, 255, 189) !important' }
})
```

The `containerCss` accept `object`.

Comment: I'm using select2 plugin and that option doesn't exists (backgroundColor).

Comment: @Percy, I upvoted you, because of your question I learned `select2`. thanks for your nice question.

Comment: @Percy, I can not understand your edition, but if you got the true answer with this edition. it is ok.